# Using FFT to approximate the CDF for an aggregate loss random variable

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, fft

Below you will find my python code for a class assignment I was given a couple weeks ago which I have been unable to successfully debug. The problem is about finding the value at risk (i.e., the p% quantile) for an aggregate loss random variable, using FFT. We are given a clear mathematical procedure by which we can gain an estimation of the discretized CDF of the aggregate loss random variable. My results are, however, seriously off and I am making some kind of mistake which I have been unable to find even after hours of debugging my code.

The aggregate loss random variable `S` is given such that `S=sum(X_i for i in range(N))`, where `N` is negative binomially distributed with `r=5, beta=.2`, and `X_i` is exponentially distributed with `theta=1`. The probability generating function for this parametrization is `P(z)=[1-\beta(z-1)]^{-r}`.

We were asked to approximate the distribution of `S` by

1. choosing a grid width `h` and an integer `n` such that `r=2^n` is the number of elements to discretize `X` on,
2. discretizing `X` and calculating the probabilities of being in equally spaced intervals of width `h`,
3. applying the FFT to the discretized `X`,
4. applying the PGF of `N` to the elements of the Fourier-transformed `X`,
5. applying the inverse FFT to this vector.

The resulting vector should be an approximation for the probability masses of each such interval for `S`. I know from previous methods that the 95% VaR ought to be ~4 and the 99.9% VaR ought to be ~10. But my code returns nonsensical results. Generally speaking, my index where the ECDF reaches levels >0.95 is way too late, and even after hours of debugging I have not managed to find where I am going wrong.

I have also asked this question on the math stackexchange, since this question is very much on the intersection of programming and math and I have no idea at this moment whether the issue is on the implementation side of things or whether I am applying the mathematical ideas wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft

r, beta, theta = 5, .2, 1
var_levels = [.95, .999]


def discretize_X(h: float, m: int):
    X = expon(scale=theta)
    f_X = [X.cdf(h / 2),
           *[X.cdf(j * h + h / 2) - X.cdf(j * h - h / 2) for j in range(1, m - 1)],
           X.sf((m - 1) * h - h / 2)]
    return f_X


# Probability generating function of N ~ NB(r, beta)
def PGF(z: [float, complex]):
    return (1 - beta * (z - 1)) ** (-r)


h = 1e-2
n = 10
r = 2 ** n

VaRs, TVaRs = [], []

# discretize X with (r-1) cells of width h and one final cell with the survival function at h*(r-1)
f_X = discretize_X(h, r)
phi_vec = fft(f_X)
f_tilde_vec_fft = np.array([PGF(phi) for phi in phi_vec])
f_S = np.real(ifft(f_tilde_vec_fft))
ecdf_S = np.cumsum(f_S)  # calc cumsum to get ECDF

for p in var_levels:
    var_idx = np.where(ecdf_S >= p)[0][0]  # get lowest index where ecdf_S >= p
    print("p =", p, "\nVaR idx:", var_idx)
    var = h * var_idx  # VaR should be this index times the cell width
    print("VaR:", var)
    tvar = 1 / (1 - p) * np.sum(f_S[var_idx:] * np.array([i * h for i in range(var_idx, r)]))  # TVaR should be each cell's probability times the value inside that cell

    VaRs.append(var)
    TVaRs.append(tvar)

return VaRs, TVaRs
```

Comment: Great question. I guess I hope you're allowed to solve the problem a different way if you see a way to do it. What I see is that the distribution of S given N is a sum of exponential variables, and that has a well-known result (I think it's gamma distributed but you should check it). Then the marginal distribution of S (i.e., summing over possible values of N) is a mixture distribution, with mixing weights equal to p(N) which you said negative binomial. You can approximate the marginal distribution with a finite summation (i.e. excluding the tail of the negative binomial).

Comment: The CDF of a mixture is just a linear combination (actually convex, since the weights sum to 1) of the CDF's of the components, which, if I remember the bit about sum(exponential) = gamma correctly, are incomplete gamma functions. Finally you can get the quantile function by any 1-dimensional root finder applied to the mixture CDF.

Comment: All that is a little more algebra and special functions, but the numerical part is much simpler. I don't know how much room you have for choosing a different direction, but anyway for my part I prefer very much to try to work with the clearest direction I can think of, maybe that works for you too. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: @RobertDodier Unfortunately, this is one of four parts with specific instructions. From other methods, I was able to compute VaR and TVaRs. So finding the values themselves is not a problem, but I have spent a lot of time on this task and I really want to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about math, but in snippet variable `r` gets overrided, and when computing `f_tilde_vec_fft` function `PGF` uses not `5` as expected for `r`, but `1024`. Fix -- change name `r` to `r_nb` in definition of hyperparameters:

`r_nb, beta, theta = 5, .2, 1`

and also in function `PGF`:

`return (1 - beta * (z - 1)) ** (-r_nb)`

After run with other parameters remain same (such as `h`, `n` etc.) for `VaRs` I get `[4.05, 9.06]`

Comment: Of course! I feel so stupid now. This is what happens when you transfer notation from mathematical formulas without considering your code base. Thanks!